# incompatible types when assigning to type 'array[256]' from type 'array *'

Tags: c

I'm quite new to C so in order to learn it I was trying to create a program which outputs a dragon curve.
Here's what I got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ebene 5

char str_n[ebene-1];
char tmp[256]; // ="1"; // 1=R, 0=L
char text[256];

int a_index=0;


char switch_middle(char iarray[256]) {
    int num=((2^a_index-1)-1)/2+1; // Nummer der Zahlen pro ebene |-1|/2|+1 -> Index des mittleren Buchstaben
    if(num>=0) {
        iarray[num]='0';
    } else {
        iarray[0]='\0';
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("Hauptschleife erreicht");

    while(a_index<ebene) {
        //snprintf(text, sizeof text, "%s1%s", tmp, switch_middle(tmp));
        strcpy(text, tmp);
        strcpy(text, "1");
        strcpy(text, switch_middle(tmp));   // Error occures here!

        //str_n[a_index]=text;
        for(long i=sizeof(tmp)/sizeof(tmp[0]); i--; ) {
                tmp[i]=text[i];
            }
        printf("Ebene: %d\n", a_index);
        //printf("  Wert: %s", str_n[a_index]);
        printf("    Wert: %d\n", text);

        a_index++; // für Mathefunktionen
    }
}
```

Trying to compile this gives me a bunch of warnings and one error; that one I mentioned in the title of this question (incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[256]' from type 'char *').
So, yeah. Any help would be appreciated (:

*Edit: Alright, the comments below fixed most of the problems; Now there is only one warning left and that is "passing argument 2 of 'strcopy' makes pointer from integer without a cast' and "expected 'const cgar * restrict' but argument is of type 'char'" as a note for the included string.h. When I try to run that program it gives me a memory access error. I marked the lines in the code above.

*Edit²: Fixed. Thanks to everyone below (:

Comment: `strcpy(text, switch_middle(tmp));`  with `char switch_middle(char iarray[256])` ?

Comment: `tmp=text;` is error again

Comment: Which line does the message correspond to?

Comment: Ok, could you mark line 31 in your code with a comment?

Comment: Arrays are not assignable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot assign arrays in C. You have two options to achieve the effect you want: Either use the `memcpy()` function (it's in the standard library, just `#include <string.h>`), or code the copy yourself:

```
for(long i = sizeof(tmp)/sizeof(tmp[0]); i--; ) tmp[i] = text[i];
```

Note that I calculated the amount of data to copy instead of just hardcoding 256, in order to prevent future bugs when you want to change the size of the involved arrays. Generally speaking, fixed limits should be avoided at nearly all costs.

Edit: For a third way to copy an array see Aarons comment.

---

Background information:

You might wonder at the text of your error message, that it reports a type mismatch where you tried to assign two variables of the same type. The reason is that array identifiers decay to a pointer to the first element of the array in almost all contexts. This is why, the right side of your assignment decayed to a `char*` while the left side remained of type `char[256]`.

Comment: Alright, that fixed the error, thanks a lot. Now trying to fix some other errors; will give feedback on whether it worked or not then (:

Comment: There is a third option for copying arrays.  Put them inside a struct.  `Struct ArrayHolder { char data[256]; }; struct  ArrayHolder tmp; struct ArrayHolder text;`  Then you can do `tmp=text;`.  But you must remember to use `tmp.data` and `text.data` in other parts of the code which actually expect the char array.

I don't recommend this approach generally, but it is a third option.

Answer (score 1):

This Line

```
 tmp=text; is wrong.
```

You are trying to change the base address of an array(tmp) which is a constant pointer.It means base address of an array can't be changed.That is why it is throwing this error.
And the warning are there because you are trying to assign a string in a character place.
This line

```
   iarray[num] = "0";
```

"0" is a string.Try to make it '0'.Now it is a character.Hence there will be 
no warning.

```
    iarray[0] = ""; //Same reason
```

Answer (score 1):

`char switch_middle(char iarray[256]) {`

should be

`char * switch_middle(char iarray[256]) {`

and you should return the array at the end:

```
char * switch_middle(char iarray[256]) {
    int num=((2^a_index-1)-1)/2+1; // Nummer der Zahlen pro ebene |-1|/2|+1 -> Index des mittleren Buchstaben
    if(num>=0) {
        iarray[num]='0';
    } else {
        iarray[0]='\0';
    }
    return iarray;
}
```

=====

On a side note, C arrays have some strange features.  For example, they are ignored in the parameter list of a function.  `char * switch_middle(char iarray[256]) {` is fully equivalent to `char * switch_middle(char * iarray) {`, and the latter is more readable.

This is weird, see example [here on ideone](http://ideone.com/O041vs).

In fact, the number inside the brackets is ignored entirely - you can change it from 256 to any other number and the program will not change behaviour!  This rule applies only to the parameters to functions.   In local variables, the number does mean something.

This means that you can't really pass an array to a function directly like that.  Yes, the outside function can send an array, but the receiving function won't see it as an array.  Frankly, I think this is a bad design in C.  I believe that compilers should give a warning if `[]` appears in parameter lists like this.